# warning: already initialized constant

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm running into a problem while trying to run my app. Whenever I start my app and to go a page, after a few seconds I get:

**Terminal Output**

http://codepad.org/Hqtd9R15

Sorry but the code was too long to post here.

Comment: It looks like the `rmagick` gem is malfunctioning and may need to be recompiled.

Answer (score 1):

```
gem 'rmagick', :require => false
```

Comment: did you restart your rails server after?